# Chainlink Oracle : Fail with error 'Must have a valid requestId'

Tags: solidity, ether, etherscan, oracles, chainlink

Facing a slight issue with my Oracle.sol that I deployed for my Naas node. whenever its fulfilling the request back to the contract, it throws this error. I deployed the contract using **"@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/Oracle.sol"** . any idea why an invalid request id may be occurring ?

**Would really appreciate any insight. I am using Solidity V 0.8.7**

**This is the error My Oracle.sol throws when its returning the response (fulfilling request)**

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x8a8277f8366259ffca71d4f63f59a7ef997d1aeed4cc39262742858f0566b42d

[image: Error i'm getting]

**I checked my Consumer contract  that makes the call to the Oracle and it seems to match the requestId that's used when my Oracle.sol and Node try to fulfill the response**

**My consumer Logs :**

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xcec2d2c3cbacfc2d5e17819e168dbce70053c94b#events

[image: Consumer logs]

**And finally, The logs from my Oracle.sol :**

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x5c1722a8b0ebb58dfa4e409745c528af4a1dbefc25338a028567837b43cd934c
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I had to make sure i had set up the right contract address in job description, and I was sending it to right address:

`contractAddress = "0x5633061EAFE5C3C2c059F1119bFE206cB8F952AB"`

`submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0x5633061EAFE5C3C2c059F1119bFE206cB8F952AB" data="$(encode_tx)"]`

Comment: seems to be matching already